# Use of undeclared identifier " sum"

Tags: objective-c, function, nslog

I have repeated error 3rd time, but I could not found that 
what is mean of use of undeclared identifier ..

I wrote that program on function in objective-C

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Add:NSObject
/* method declaration */
 - (int)add:(int)a andNum2:(int)b;
@end

@implementation Add

/* method returning the max between two numbers */
 - (int)add:(int)a andNum2:(int)b{
/* local variable declaration */


int sum = a +b;
return sum;
}

@end

  NSLog(@"sum is : %d", sum);// error this line     
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sum` is a local variable - you can't access it from outside the function. This is very basic stuff, so I suggest you might want to get a good book on C/Objective C.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Add:NSObject{

  int sum;//Declare sum as global variable to access in class
 }
  - (int)add:(int)a andNum2:(int)b;
 @end

 @implementation Add

   - (int)add:(int)a andNum2:(int)b{

   sum = a +b;//
   return sum;
}

@end

NSLog(@"sum is : %d", sum);//Now Access global variable with in class
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the exact code? if yes then first you need to call

```
NSLog(@"sum is : %d", sum);
return 0;
```

inside some function.

Also sum is a variable declared inside `add` method and thus cannot be used outside that function. Declare `sum` under `@interface Add:NSOBject` to use it out side `add` method.

If you don't want to declare it outside `add` method then change the line

```
NSLog(@"sum is : %d", sum);
```

to

```
NSLog(@"sum is : %d", [add:@(12) andNum2:@(13)]);
```

(Note: Replace 12 and 13 with any other number or numeric variable)

Comment: /* local variable definition */
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;
    
    
   when i was replacing shown error i.e  unused variable a, b
    
    NSLog(@"sum is : %d", [Add:@(10) andNumb2:@(20)]);
    
    retur

Comment: replace `@(10)` and `@(20)` with `a` and `b` respectively. i.e. `NSLog(@"sum is : %d", [Add:a andNumb2:b]);`